# Python Letter Changer

Tags: python, list, random, function

I am working on a program that gets a string from any variable (var, var2) and changes the vowel to any random vowel. I have attempted to do so but my code doesn't work, it always prints there is no vowel.

```
import random
alph = list('abcdefgkijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
vow = list('aeiou')
Alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p', 'q' ,'r' ,'s', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x' ,'y','z']
Vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
Consences = ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p', 'q' ,'r' ,'s', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x' ,'y','z']

ranVowel= random.choice(Vowels)
print(ranVowel)


var2 = ['i']
var = list("cat")

def ifVowel(x):
    if (Vowels in x):
        print 'there is a vowel'
        var[var.index(vow)] = ranVowel
    elif (Vowels not in x):
        print 'there is no vowel'
    else: print 'no vowels'

ifVowel(var2)
```

Comment: "but my code doesn't work": although in this case the problem is pretty easy to spot, that's not specific enough to be part of a good question.  What did you expect your code to do?  What does your code do instead?  What part of the code can you narrow the unexpected behaviour down to?  What are the values and types of the involved variables at that point?  Et cetera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test

```
if (Vowels in x):
```

is checking whether the whole list `Vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']` is `in x`, and will probably never be `True`. Instead, you want:

```
if any(vowel in x for vowel in Vowels):
```

which tests each one individually. Also

```
var[var.index(vow)] = ranVowel
```

will only replace the first vowel. You need to loop over your string to replace all vowels, for example:

```
replaced = "".join(c if c not in Vowels else random.choice(Vowels) for c in x)
```

Note that all of this will only work for lower case, so you might want to use `x.lower()` or deal with upper case explicitly.

Finally, things that aren't vowels are consonants.

Answer (score 3):

Could just use `re` with a function replacement..., eg:

```
>>> import re, random
>>> vowels = 'aeiou'
>>> text = 'this is something with vowels in'
>>> re.sub('[aeiou]', lambda L: random.choice(vowels), text, flags=re.I)
'thos is semithung wath vawuls in'
```

Comment: I would expect this to be the most effective and efficient solution. +1